# Do I get bonus points for undercut with gin?

Tags: gin-rummy

Let’s say I get gin, but I don’t knock. Then my opponent knocks with deadwood of 8. Since I have gin, do I get the bonus points for both the gin and undercut, plus the difference of 8? If not, what bonus do I get?

Comment: Not a duplicate because the opponent did not have gin.

Comment: The issue is that the answer to both question are answered with the same rule text.

Comment: The situations are totally different though. One is asking about undercutting gin (you can't) and one is asking if gin applies to an undercut (it doesn't). That's two separate rules.

Comment: See also this [meta on another site](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/951/should-different-questions-that-yield-similar-duplicate-answers-be-closed/956#956)

Comment: right, two different questions with the same answer, should be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with only getting the underknock bonus since you didn't knock.  I would argue that the Gin bonus is only given to the player that knocks since it is given for getting rid of all dead wood through meld when knocking. If you are playing the second player gets both bonuses it changes how the game is played since there is an advantage to sitting on gin since you might be able to pick up both bonuses.

relevant text (bold added by me to show relevant text)

In standard gin, a player with 10 or fewer points of deadwood may knock, immediately ending the hand without giving the opponent a chance to play. **Knocking with no deadwood is known as going Gin or having a Gin hand, while knocking with deadwood points is known as going down**.[6]

After discarding to end a turn, a player who wishes to knock must clearly indicate their intent; this is generally shown by laying the discard face down, but can also be done through a verbal declaration or by tapping the playing surface. The player then lays out their hand, organized into melds and with any deadwood separated from them. The opponent, or "defending" player, shows their melds and is entitled to lay off any deadwood cards that fit into the knocking player's melds, provided that the knocking player does not have a gin hand.

For example, suppose that the knocking player has a meld of three Kings. If the defending player is holding the fourth King as deadwood, they may lay it off by adding it to the meld and thus reduce their deadwood count by 10.

The difference in the two players' deadwood counts determines the score for the hand as follows.

If the knocking player has the lower count, they score points equal to the difference.
**The defending player can undercut the knocking player by having a lower or equal count. In this case, the defending player scores the difference plus a bonus (usually 15 points). An undercut may occur either before or after the defending player has laid off any deadwood.**
The knocking player can never lay off their deadwood into the defending player's melds.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gin_rummy

Comment: This matches the way I understand it.  It amounts to a minor penalty (depending on how an undercut is scored) for not paying attention.

Comment: Having the second player get both bonus basically makes it so it is an advantage not to knock with Gin unless you think they will get Gin before you.

Comment: Rather thah just linking to the game rules, it would be more helpful if you were to also quote the specific relevant rules. Otherwise this citation is more like "it's in there somewhere, promise".

Answer (score 3):

### You only get the Undercut bonus + the 8 deadwood difference.

Gin can be made only by the active player. Source: [pagat:Gin Rummy](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/ginrummy.html)

> Knocking with no unmatched cards at all is called going gin

The following sentence casually explains that the non-active player that has zero deadwood did not made gin.

> Even if the other player has no unmatched cards at all, the person going gin gets the 20 point bonus the other player scores nothing.

@Styxsksu's answer is 100% correct, my answer cites [pagat](https://www.pagat.com/) which is  better source for rules of cards games.

Comment: This seems like a comment (a correction to the terms being used) rather than an answer. It doesn't seem to address the question.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson, I have edit the header to better answer the question.